# Small animation with Raphael

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, raphael.js, animation

I have a small animation with Raphael using a large amount of code.  Is there any way to reduce it?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V54hR/1/)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.colbr');
    for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var loadSpinner = spinner(elements[i], 7, 12, 10, 3, "#000");
    }
};

function spinner(holderid, R1, R2, count, stroke_width, colour) {
    var sectorsCount = count || 12,
        // color = colour || "#000",
        color = "#000",
        width = stroke_width || 15,
        r1 = Math.min(R1, R2) || 35,
        r2 = Math.max(R1, R2) || 60,
        cx = r2 + width,
        cy = r2 + width,
        r = Raphael(holderid, r2 * 2 + width * 2, r2 * 2 + width * 2),

        sectors = [],
        opacity = [],
        beta = 2 * Math.PI / sectorsCount,

        pathParams = {stroke: color, "stroke-width": width, "stroke-linecap": "round"};
        Raphael.getColor.reset();
    for (var i = 0; i < sectorsCount; i++) {
        var alpha = beta * i - Math.PI / 2,
            cos = Math.cos(alpha),
            sin = Math.sin(alpha);
        opacity[i] = 1 / sectorsCount * i;
        sectors[i] = r.path([["M", cx + r1 * cos, cy + r1 * sin], ["L", cx + r2 * cos, cy + r2 * sin]]).attr(pathParams);
        if (color == "rainbow") {
            sectors[i].attr("stroke", Raphael.getColor());
        }
    }
    var tick;
    (function ticker() {
        opacity.unshift(opacity.pop());
        for (var i = 0; i < sectorsCount; i++) {
            sectors[i].attr("opacity", opacity[i]);
        }
        r.safari();
        tick = setTimeout(ticker, 1000 / sectorsCount);
    })();
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(tick);
        r.remove();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like what you wrote there, though I am afraid at this point you ought to expand the code, not reduce it.

- `r`, `r1`, `r2`, `cx`, `cy`, `beta` are all variables that need better ( more meaningful ) names
- You need to indent your code, just hit <kbd>TidyUp</kbd> in your fiddle and you will see
- This is not part of your core code, but you should not simply assign something to `window.onload`, you should use `addEventListener`
- Your code had support for using custom colors, and then you took it out, if you really want to take that out, then you should also take out the parameter, the commented out code and the  `if (color == "rainbow"){` statement
- in your `var` statement, you could simply do `cy = cx`
- be consistent in your name, and use lowerCamelCase: `stroke_width` -> `strokeWidth`
- You did not declare `i` with `var`
- While straightforward, your code has no comments at all..

Comment: You could use `<kbd>` instead of the tag notation, for `tidyup`.